# How to use parser combinators to parse a stream of XMLEvents?

Tags: xml, scala, parsing, parser-combinators

Suppose I need to read an XML lazily. I am using [XMLEventReader](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.xml.pull.XMLEventReader) that returns a `stream` (lazy list) of [XMLEvents](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.xml.pull.XMLEvent). I would like to *parse* this stream in order to transform it to a stream of some domain objects.

For example, I would like to transform the XML `<xs><x><s>aaa</s></x><x><s>bbb</s></x><x><s>ccc</s></x></xs>` into a stream of instances of `case class X(s: String)`

I would like to use `parser combinators`. I can define a parser of the input stream of `XMLEvents` as a wrapper class over function `Stream[XMLEvent] => Option[(A, Stream[XMLEvent])]` with `map` and `flatMap`:

```
import scala.xml.pull._ 

type Events = Stream[XMLEvent]

type Result[A] = Option[(A, Events)]

class Parser[A](run: Events => Result[A]) {

  def apply(es: Events) = run(es)

  def map[B](f: A => B): Parser[B] = new Parser (
    es => this(es) map {case (a, rest) => (f(a), rest)}
  )

  def flatMap[B](f: A => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = new Parser (
    es => this(es) flatMap {case (a, rest) => f(a)(rest)}
  )
}
```

Does it make sense ? How can I *reuse* the standard [scala parser combinators](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.11.5/scala-parser-combinators/#package) library instead of writing my own `class Parser[A](run: Events => Result[A])` as in above ?

Comment: It's possible to feed `XMLEvent`s to a standard library parser and write combinators of those events. But it may be impossible or really hacky to have scala library produce streams. (Maybe someone can correct me?) `Parser[T]` in the standard library is a function `Input => ParseResult[T]`. `Input` can be lazy, but `ParseResult` must have a field `next: Input`, and to know at what position `next` is, you have to parse the whole `Stream`. It may be possible to define a custom `I <: Input`, which finds this position lazily, but Stream will be forced if you have some parser after the stream one.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Do you know any other parser combinator library, which works with `streams` ?

Comment: No, sorry. Now that I think of it parser combinators as a concept don't work with streams. I believe the concept of processing and composing data streams is represented by Iteratees (+ enumerators and enumeratees).You may wish to explore scalaz or Play Iteratee functionality.

Comment: Why do you think that parser combinators don't work with streams ? Thanks for pointing me out to `iteratees` anyway :)

Comment: I'm probably wrong about that. Seems Haskell Parsec can be lazy. Here is some more reasoning for standard scala library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014207/scala-parser-combinators-parsing-in-a-stream